# How to resolve host names under a wifi router?

Tags: networking, hosts

Is it possible to resolve host names by using a DNS server that resides behind the router and has a local IP? I was able to manage this by modifying the **hosts** file under `Windows/System32` My aim is to be able have two laptops in the my home wi-fi network be able to resolve each other using their host names.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest thing to do is just use the hosts file like you did. 
You can definitely have your own DNS server behind your router/firewall.
What type of router do you have?  It might be able to provide this functionality.

Otherwise, you could set up a small Linux server to run your local DNS services.
Although, if you've only got 2 computers, setting up a DNS server for that is a little overkill.

You can build it yourself in Linux: http://mixeduperic.com/ubuntu/seven-easy-steps-to-setting-up-an-interal-dns-server-on-ubuntu.html

Or, you can download a pre-made Linux DNS VM, like this: https://www.turnkeylinux.org/core
or this: https://www.turnkeylinux.org/domain-controller